# How to display file properties via terminal?

Tags: command-line, permissions, file-properties

What is the command line that displays file informations (or properties), such as in GUI method *Display properties* in GNOME?

[image: Display properties GNOME]

I know that `ls -l` shows properties; but how to display the same informations?

For example, instead of

```
rw-rw-r--
```

we have such GUI rendering:

```
abdennour@estifeda: $wishedCmd myFile
 ..... 
  Permissions : 
    Owner Access: Read & write 
    Group Access :Read & Write 
    Others Access: Read only
   .....
```

[image: Screenshot of permissions dialogue]

Comment: What about `stat`? That will give you a huge amount of information on a selected file or folder; see `man stat`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Something like

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
print_perm() {
  case "$1" in
    0) printf "NO PERMISSIONS";;
    1) printf "Execute only";;
    2) printf "Write only";;
    3) printf "Write & execute";;
    4) printf "Read only";;
    5) printf "Read & execute";;
    6) printf "Read & write";;
    7) printf "Read & write & execute";;
  esac
}

[[ ! -e $1 ]] &&  echo "$0 <file or dir>" 2>&1 && exit 1

perm=$(stat -c%a "$1")
user=${perm:0:1}
group=${perm:1:1}
global=${perm:2:1}

echo "Permissions :"
printf "\tOwner Access: $(print_perm $user)\n"
printf "\tGroup Access: $(print_perm $group)\n"
printf "\tOthers Access: $(print_perm $global)\n"
```

Output

```bsh
# rwxr-x--- foo*
> ./abovescript foo
Permissions :
    Owner Access: Read & write & execute
    Group Access: Read & execute
    Others Access: NO PERMISSIONS
```

Answer (score 165):

Use the `stat` command to know the details of the file. If file name is `file_name`, use

```
stat file_name
```

Answer (score 41):

There is no dedicated command for this. For meta information like time, size and access rights, use

```
ls -l path-to-file
```

You might also be interested in what kind of file it is, `file path-to-file` will help you with that.

Answer (score 32):

Have you tried `file`?

For example:

```
file picture.jpg
```

Comment: I'm sure he meant permissions.

Answer (score 13):

```
ls -lh filename
```

for human readable version

Comment: This makes the filesize "readable". You get 32K instead of 31900. But does not help for access rights. But helpful anyway ;-)

Comment: Yea slight change, but not having to do mental size conversion is a plus. Good tip.

Answer (score 3):

## Display the attributes of the files in the current directory:

lsattr

## List the attributes of files in a particular path:

lsattr path

## List file attributes recursively in the current and subsequent directories:

lsattr -R

## Show attributes of all the files in the current directory, including hidden ones:

lsattr -a

## Display attributes of directories in the current directory:

lsattr -d

Comment: is there a way to see if the file is a 32 or 64 bit executable?

Comment: In **Terminal** you can use : 

 `` objdump -f file.exe ``

 you'II see file format output like this : `

``
 file.exe: file format pei-i386 architecture: i386, flags 0x0000..: EXEC_P, HAS_DEBUG, D_PAGED start address 0x00402....
 ``

 So file format pei-i386 => 32bit 

**Other** method to check out what format the executable file has. using ` file ` command as example: 

`` $ file myfile.exe `` 

 response > myfile.exe: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows ```

Comment: I tried the objdump way first and got "file format not recognized" then when I used the file command got "POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable, with very long lines"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ls` command to list files and their properties by adding the `-l` option.
Example:

```
$ls -l filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ls -l filename
```

**(use small L)**

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [*Linux Pocket Guide* by Daniel J. Barrett](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-pocket-guide/9780596806347/ch01s13.html) you can **list extended attributes of files and directories** with:

```
lsattr file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following script:

```
set filepath "$HOME/.bashrc"
set fileuri $(echo $filepath | python -c "import sys, pathlib; print(pathlib.Path(input()).resolve().as_uri())")
dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.FileManager1 /org/freedesktop/FileManager1 org.freedesktop.FileManager1.ShowItemProperties array:string:"$fileuri" string:""
```

**P.S.** If you do not convert file path to file uri then path like `$HOME/Desktop/directory with spaces and ümläuts.txt` will not work.